# How to get data from one column in a different table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope, self

I have a ruby on rails application and am trying to display the star rating a user gave a product on the index page. I only need the number of stars column but nothing I am doing seems to work, can someone please help.

In my index.html.erb I have the following code:

```
Your star rating: <%= number_with_precision(product.user_star_rating, :precision => 1)%>
```

And the method in my product.rb:

```
has_many :reviews
belongs_to :category
def user_star_rating
    user_id = session[:user_id]
    scope :userrating, -> { where('user_id = ?', user_id)}
    self.reviews.user_id('no_of_stars')
end
```

In my reviews.rb I have the relationships:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :user

validates :review_text, :presence => { :message => "Review text: cannot be blank ..."}
validates :review_text, :length =>   {:maximum => 2000, :message => "Review text: maximum length 2000 characters"} 

validates :no_of_stars, :presence => { :message => "Stars: please rate this book ..."}
```

In the line     self.reviews.user_id('no_of_stars') I am trying to retrieve the number of stars that particular user has given for the product and return it, but I am not sure if any of the code in this method is right.

Can someone please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is this self.reviews.user_id('no_of_stars') ? 
are you counting the number of reviews of this product  ? 
Please provide more info specially on the logic, how you are calculating the rating of a product ?

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information that you provided I am not quite sure how you are approaching or structuring your logic here.  But this is how I would easily achieve retrieving a User's star rating for a particular product.

Have at a minimum the following Schema:

**Reviews Table**

```
user_id, :integer
product_id, :integer
rating, :integer
```

And set up your models with the following:

**Review.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

**Product.rb**

```
has_many :reviews
```

**User.rb**

```
has_many :reviews
```

make sure to add indexes

Then when a user creates a review for a product it can be accessed by fetching the correct Review in your controller:

```
@review = Review.where(:user_id => params[:user_id], :product_id => params[:product_id]).first
```

Then in your html.erb file you can display the User's rating for the product

```
"Your star rating: <%= @review.rating %>"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've uploaded the existing relationships in my review.rb and product.rb model, replacing these with your's doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: With the little information that you initially provided I was trying to lead you down the right path of how to think about structuring your code to achieve your desired result in a clean manner.  I have updated my answer to include the minimum schema configuration, Model, Controller, and View code that is needed to display a User's star rating for a product.

Comment: That still doesn't work, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Ok.  Sorry I made a typo above where I put :product instead of :product_id in the .where call.  I corrected it.  This setup should work for you.  If you are getting error's make sure that the proper records are created.

Comment: @benjs.1 how did this work for you?  I feel I provided sufficient information to solve your question, if you feel the same please mark this answer as the correct answer for your question.